# How do I create a subgroup generated by the relations of a group G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H$ is a free abelian group with presentation $\langle G, R \rangle$ with $G, R$ meaning generators and relations, respectively, what does it mean to say "$F$ is the subgroup generated by the relations $R$"?

Since relations are written in some form like $
\langle G, a^2=b^3=c^4, df=jk, \text{ etc... } \rangle$, how could I create a subgroup generated by the relations?

Comment: You rather want *relators*, like $dfk^{-1}j^{-1}$, $a^2b^{-3}$, etc, and then you take the normal subgroup generated by those. This then forces the relations you want to hold in the quotient.

Comment: What do you mean by "generated by those"?  Since each element of those elements equals the identity, wouldn't any successive operation just remain the identity and the set generated by the elements would be trivial?

Comment: What is the "normal subgroup generated by those" I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any relation, we can use the inverse of one side to transform it into a relation saying that some string is equal to the identity: e.g. your group might be written $\langle a,b,c,d,f,j,k | a^2 b^{-3}=b^3 c^{-4} = d f k^{-1} j^{-1} = id \rangle$.

Then, we have some set of strings which the relations set as equal to the identity, which generates some subgroup $R$ of the free group $F$ on the generators. In your example, we get a subgroup of the free group $F[a,b,c,d,f,j,k]$ generated by the elements $\langle a^2 b^{-3}, b^3 c^{-4}, d f k^{-1} j^{-1} \rangle$ and we can extend that a normal closure of that subgroup $\langle\langle a^2 b^{-3}, b^3 c^{-4}, d f k^{-1} j^{-1} \rangle\rangle$.

The point then is that the quotient group $F/R$ is isomorphic to the group we are trying to construct. e.g. $F[a,b,c,d,f,j,k]/\langle \langle a^2 b^{-3}, b^3 c^{-4}, d f k^{-1} j^{-1} \rangle \rangle = 
\langle G| a^2=b^3=c^4, df=jk\rangle$.

Comment: But how do you construct the subgroup from the relations set?  What are the elements the subgroup and how are they constructed from the relations?

Comment: I'll add in some more details based on your example.

Comment: I don't understand.  If $H$ is a free abelian group with presentation $\langle G| R \rangle$ and I'm trying to construct a subgroup $F$ of $H$ generated by the relations $R$ from the presentation of $H$, what specifically does an element of $F$ look like?  What form is it in?  If $R =r_1, r_2, ..., r_k  $ are the relations, then I would assume that an element of $F$ would be of the form $r_1^{n_1} + r_2^{n_2} + ... + r_k^{n_k}$.  But each relation $r_j$ is already an identity in the presentation $\langle G| R \rangle$, so since $r_j = \text{ identity }$, isn't each element of $F$ the identity?

Comment: I must admit I'm not sure what you mean by "free (abelian) group with presentation $\langle G|R \rangle$". The entire point of free (abelian) groups is they are entirely determined by the generators: either as sums of multiples of generators for free abelian groups, or strings of generators and their inverses for free groups in general.
This suggests a rather tricky misconception about what's going on here.

Comment: The point of this construction is that every group $G$ is the quotient of a free group $F$, with the generators telling you which free group to use and the relations which (normal) subgroup to quotient out by.

While each element of the subgroup is eventually sent to the identity under the quotient map, they are not the identity in the original free group. The question of which words are in that subgroup generated by the relations is a very tricky one, especially in the context of non-abelian groups.